# How can i assign formValidity as value of a HTML5 element that is two way binded by ngModel

Tags: html, angular, validation, forms

I have to pass the `boolean` value gotten from `myForm.valid` to my Angular 2 component. It is a template driven form. Getting it in the component by means of two-way binding is what I want to achieve. The code below doesn't work. How can I get the value of `myForm.valid` to my Angular 2 component?

```
<form #myForm=“ngForm">
.
.
<input type="hidden" id="isValid" name="isValid" [(ngModel)]="isValid" value="myForm.valid"/>
.
.
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: now you should see the code. thanks!

Comment: is it a reactive or template driven form?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by 2-way binding here, but since you are trying to bring the form's validity status to a component property (in a template driven form, it is easier to do so in a reactive form, FYI), you don't have to tie it to one of the `input` element's properties. You can directly determine that using `@ViewChild()` decorator to fetch the template reference variable of your form, `myForm` (see in template, `<form #myForm=“ngForm">`).

> component

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core;
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit { // has to implement this interface along with other interfaces you may have

@ViewChild(NgForm) form: NgForm;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 console.log(this.form.valid); // gives you the form's validity status
}
```

But having a 2-way binding here doesn't make sense - meaning changing that value in the component doesn't necessarily mean your form automagically becomes valid. It is a state (of the form) which you can observe from within the component at any time. Only thing to keep in mind is, this `this.form` property in the component is only available after the `ngAfterViewInit()` life-cycle hook. You can check up on its status anytime after this, for example in a method that gets triggered based on a event or something to that effect.